# Tweak D3 calendar view example to be vertical with days be ordered left to right, then top to bottom?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

See original gallery example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318

The way the example works, the days are ordered top to bottom, then left to right.  Hover over them to see what I mean.  What I want is something more like a regular vertical calendar, where the months are stacked vertically on top of each other and the days are numbered left to right, then top to bottom.  See mock up:

[image]

Rotating the entire month stack is not too bad but I'm tripping up on SVG drawing the edge cases involved from months not having all having the same number of days.

Anybody willing to to alter the layout algorithm to do it this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I think you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/d3y14zsq/1/ (only uses the last 3 years of data)

First I put each of the years (a separate SVG element) into a `div` and used some CSS (in `.container` and `.block`) to align horizontally.

Actually switching the cells for each day to display years vertically is easy: switching the `x` and `y` in this bit of code:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return week(d) * cellSize; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return day(d) * cellSize; })
```

And also switching `height` and `width` values around

The tricky bit is certainly the path for the month outlines, which is built up manually in `monthPath`. After some trial-and-error, this is what I came up with:

```
return "M" + d0 * cellSize + "," + (w0) * cellSize 
    + "H" + 7 * cellSize + "V" + (w1) * cellSize 
    + "H" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize
    + "H" + 0 + "V" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "H" 
    + d0 * cellSize + "Z";
```

Basically I swapped the `H` and `V` lines about, but also had to fiddle with it for a while to get it to work

I modified the transform on the `g` element to give space at the top of each year for the text label, rather than to the left. I also tidied up a bit by adding a new `paddingSize` variable so there's a bit less hard-coded positioning (although there is still some)

```
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + paddingSize + ",15)");
```

Finally I positioned the label text for the years.