# How to add day numbers to D3 calendar heatmap?

Tags: d3.js

I'm working with a modified version of Mike Bostock's Calendar Heatmap (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318). In this version, I rotated the calendar and I'm just focusing on a few months (this was helpful: [Tweak D3 calendar view example to be vertical with days be ordered left to right, then top to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913266/tweak-d3-calendar-view-example-to-be-vertical-with-days-be-ordered-left-to-right)). See the attached image. [image]

Does anyone have ideas on how to add small font day numbers to each of the day rectangles? They would be font size 8, and in the corners of each day's rectangle. I've been fiddling with it for hours and haven't gotten anywhere.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 550,
    height = 750,
    cellSize = 45;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".1%");

var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range(["#ffffff","#e6f7ff","#b3e6ff","#99ddff","#66ccff","#4dc3ff","#1ab2ff","#0077b3","#004466"]);

var month_strings = ["January", "February", "March"]

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data([2018])
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 5) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 16 - 1) + ")");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10," + cellSize * 3 + ")rotate(-90)")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", 20)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(month_strings[0]);

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10," + cellSize * 7 + ")rotate(-90)")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", 20)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(month_strings[1]);

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10," + cellSize * 11 + ")rotate(-90)")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", 20)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(month_strings[2]);




var rect = svg.append("g")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#d2d4d8")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d3.timeDays(new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date(2018, 3, 1)); })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .attr("class", "hour bordered")
    .attr("rx", 4)
    .attr("ry", 4)
    //.attr("x", function(d) { return d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(d), d) * cellSize; })
    //.attr("y", function(d) { return d.getDay() * cellSize; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.getDay() * cellSize;})
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(d), d) * cellSize;  })   
    .datum(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"));





svg.append("g")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) { return d3.timeMonths(new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date(2018, 3, 1)); })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", pathMonth);

d3.csv("static/test.csv", function(error, csv) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
      .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Close - d[0].Open) / d[0].Open; })
    .object(csv);

  rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(data[d]); })
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + formatPercent(data[d]); });



});

function pathMonth(t0) {
  var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
      d0 = t0.getDay(), w0 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t0), t0),
      d1 = t1.getDay(), w1 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t1), t1);
return "M" + d0 * cellSize + "," + (w0) * cellSize 
    + "H" + 7 * cellSize + "V" + (w1) * cellSize 
    + "H" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize
    + "H" + 0 + "V" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "H" 
    + d0 * cellSize + "Z";
}

var start_box = svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 225)
      .attr("y", 45)
      .attr("width", cellSize)
      .attr("height", cellSize)
      .attr("rx", 4)
      .attr("ry", 4)
      .attr("class", "hour bordered")
      .style("fill", "#FFD700");



</script>
```

Here is the CSV:

```
Date,Weekday,Open,Close
2018-01-01,0,1,0
2018-01-02,1,1,1
2018-01-03,2,1,2
2018-01-04,3,1,3
2018-01-05,4,1,4
2018-01-06,5,1,1
2018-01-07,6,1,1
2018-01-08,0,1,7
2018-01-09,1,1,8
2018-01-10,2,1,9
2018-01-11,3,1,10
2018-01-12,4,1,11
2018-01-13,5,1,1
2018-01-14,6,1,1
2018-01-15,0,1,14
2018-01-16,1,1,15
2018-01-17,2,1,16
2018-01-18,3,1,17
2018-01-19,4,1,18
2018-01-20,5,1,1
2018-01-21,6,1,1
2018-01-22,0,1,21
2018-01-23,1,1,22
2018-01-24,2,1,23
2018-01-25,3,1,24
2018-01-26,4,1,25
2018-01-27,5,1,1
2018-01-28,6,1,1
2018-01-29,0,1,28
2018-01-30,1,1,29
2018-01-31,2,1,30
2018-02-01,3,1,31
2018-02-02,4,1,32
2018-02-03,5,1,1
2018-02-04,6,1,1
2018-02-05,0,1,35
2018-02-06,1,1,36
2018-02-07,2,1,37
2018-02-08,3,1,38
2018-02-09,4,1,39
2018-02-10,5,1,1
2018-02-11,6,1,1
2018-02-12,0,1,42
2018-02-13,1,1,43
2018-02-14,2,1,44
2018-02-15,3,1,45
2018-02-16,4,1,46
2018-02-17,5,1,1
2018-02-18,6,1,1
2018-02-19,0,1,49
2018-02-20,1,1,50
2018-02-21,2,1,51
2018-02-22,3,1,52
2018-02-23,4,1,53
2018-02-24,5,1,1
2018-02-25,6,1,1
2018-02-26,0,1,56
2018-02-27,1,1,57
2018-02-28,2,1,58
2018-03-01,3,1,59
2018-03-02,4,1,60
2018-03-03,5,1,1
2018-03-04,6,1,1
2018-03-05,0,1,63
2018-03-06,1,1,64
2018-03-07,2,1,65
2018-03-08,3,1,66
2018-03-09,4,1,67
2018-03-10,5,1,1
2018-03-11,6,1,1
2018-03-12,0,1,70
2018-03-13,1,1,71
2018-03-14,2,1,72
2018-03-15,3,1,73
2018-03-16,4,1,74
2018-03-17,5,1,1
2018-03-18,6,1,1
2018-03-19,0,1,77
2018-03-20,1,1,78
2018-03-21,2,1,79
2018-03-22,3,1,80
2018-03-23,4,1,81
2018-03-24,5,1,1
2018-03-25,6,1,1
2018-03-26,0,1,84
2018-03-27,1,1,85
2018-03-28,2,1,86
2018-03-29,3,1,87
2018-03-30,4,1,88
2018-03-31,5,1,1
```

Comment: By the way, these are the 2018 calendars for Jan-March

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var width = 550,
      height = 750,
      cellSize = 45;

    var formatPercent = d3.format(".1%");

    var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range(["#ffffff", "#e6f7ff", "#b3e6ff", "#99ddff", "#66ccff", "#4dc3ff", "#1ab2ff", "#0077b3", "#004466"]);

    var month_strings = ["January", "February", "March"]

    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .selectAll("svg")
      .data([2018])
      .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 5) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 16 - 1) + ")");

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10," + cellSize * 3 + ")rotate(-90)")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 20)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(month_strings[0]);

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10," + cellSize * 7 + ")rotate(-90)")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 20)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(month_strings[1]);

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10," + cellSize * 11 + ")rotate(-90)")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 20)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(month_strings[2]);

    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#d2d4d8")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d3.timeDays(new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date(2018, 3, 1));
      })
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d){
        var x = d.getDay() * cellSize,
            y = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(d), d) * cellSize;
        return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
      })
      
    g.append("rect")
      .attr("width", cellSize)
      .attr("height", cellSize)
      .attr("class", "hour bordered")
      .attr("rx", 4)
      .attr("ry", 4)
      .datum(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"));
      
    g.append("text")
      .text(function(d){
        return d.getDate();
      })
      .attr("y", cellSize)
      .style("font-family", "arial")
      .style("font-size", "8pt")

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d3.timeMonths(new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date(2018, 3, 1));
      })
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", pathMonth);

    d3.csv("static/test.csv", function(error, csv) {
      if (error) throw error;

      var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.Date;
        })
        .rollup(function(d) {
          return (d[0].Close - d[0].Open) / d[0].Open;
        })
        .object(csv);

      rect.filter(function(d) {
          return d in data;
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return color(data[d]);
        })
        .append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d + ": " + formatPercent(data[d]);
        });



    });

    function pathMonth(t0) {
      var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
        d0 = t0.getDay(),
        w0 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t0), t0),
        d1 = t1.getDay(),
        w1 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t1), t1);
      return "M" + d0 * cellSize + "," + (w0) * cellSize + "H" + 7 * cellSize + "V" + (w1) * cellSize + "H" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize + "H" + 0 + "V" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "H" + d0 * cellSize + "Z";
    }

    var start_box = svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 225)
      .attr("y", 45)
      .attr("width", cellSize)
      .attr("height", cellSize)
      .attr("rx", 4)
      .attr("ry", 4)
      .attr("class", "hour bordered")
      .style("fill", "#FFD700");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this! It seems though that the dynamic colors for each of the days is no longer there. Also, I got an error saying that "rect is not defined". Referring to this line: "rect.filter(function(d) {..."  Is there a way to just superimpose the day numbers on top of the squares without changing the coloring?

Comment: Also, I added the CSV if that helps

Comment: @Slyron, opps, my bad, missed that part of your code.  [Here it is fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/MJqeZx2unk0JDzj1ukJG?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks again. Since you're somewhat familiar with this code, do you have any thoughts on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994092/d3-fill-transition-for-heatmap-not-working